# yahoo.com will not open in mozilla firefox

Tags: browser

When I try to open yahoo.com in mozilla firefox I get the following error.  An error occurred during a connection to www.yahoo.com. Invalid OCSP signing certificate in OCSP response. (Error code: sec_error_ocsp_invalid_signing_cert)

what should i do?

Comment: [Googling the error would be a good start](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1013172)

Comment: This is an application support question, not an InfoSec question.

Comment: Double check if your system date is correct. If it's in the past or future, the certificate would be invalid.